# Añadir multiples registros a una lista usando el mismo objeto

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un problema al trabajar con listas y objetos, les pongo el siguiente ejemplo:

Tengo una clase llamada `Producto` y tiene una propiedad: `string Nombre`

Supongamos esta situación:

```
Producto unProducto = new Producto();
unProducto.Nombre = "Pelota";
```

Creo una lista para almacenar dicho `Producto`:

```
List<Producto> ListaProductos = new List<Producto>();
```

Agrego `unProducto` a la `ListaProductos`:

```
ListaProductos.Add(unProducto);
```

Aquí viene el problema, si yo quisiera modificar el objeto `unProducto` para agregar otro a la lista sin tener que declarar otro `Producto` (supongamos que necesito hacer esto infinitas veces), haría lo siguiente:

```
unProducto.Nombre = "Auto";
ListaProductos.Add(unProducto);
```

Pero voy a tener dos elementos en mi lista llamados de manera igual, ya que es el mismo objeto. ¿Hay alguna manera de agregar multiples objetos a partir del mismo sin necesidad de declarar un objeto para uno de la lista?

Comment: Si entendí bien , quizá podría enviarlo directamente haciendo uso de un constructor `ListaProductos.Add(new Producto("Auto"));`

Comment: Lo que necesito es declarar un producto, agregarlo a la lista, modificarlo, agregarlo de nuevo a la lista como otro producto distinto, modificarlo, y así sucesivamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para este tipo de detalles podría  hacer uso de los constructores que se pueden crean dentro de la clase *(Producto)* y no necesariamente crear un objeto u modificar uno ya existente.

Al  modificar un atributo de un objeto se estará modificando el mismo objeto en memoria. pero la lista tendrá la referencia del mismo objeto añadido dos veces.

Entonces si usted tiene algo como :

```
List<Producto> listProduct = new List<Producto>();
Producto produc = new Producto();
produc.Nombre = "Pelota";

listProduct.Add(produc);
produc.Nombre = "Computadora";
listProduct.Add(produc);
/*Su resultado será "Computadora","Computadora" */
```

Haciendo uso de los constructores de la clase podría ser tan simple como :

```
 class Producto
{
   private String nombre;

    public Producto(){ }

    /*Constructor*/
    public Producto(string nombre)
    {
        this.Nombre = nombre;
    }

    public string Nombre{
        get {return nombre;}
        set{  nombre = value;}
    }
}
```

Para luego solo añadir

```
List<Producto> listProduct = new List<Producto>();
listProduct.Add(new Producto("Auto"));
listProduct.Add(new Producto("Computadora"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Estimado,

La lista sólo es un contenedor de posiciones de memoria de los objetos que agregues. No hace copias del objeto al agregarlo.

Cada objeto posee una única posición de memoria, por lo que si no cambias de objeto al almacenarlo, sólo estará agregando muchas veces el mismo. Esto no tiene mucho sentido ni utilidad.

Te recomiendo que si no puedes crear nuevos objetos de tipo producto inicialmente por cada uno de ellos, crees un nuevo objeto y hazle una copia de sus propiedades antes de agregarlo a la lista, y que sea la copia la almacenada en ella. Te serviría en dicho caso implementar un constructor que reciba un tipo de objeto Producto y dentro de él implementar la copia.

Ejemplo:

```
public Producto(Producto original) {
    this.Nombre = original.Nombre;
};
```

De esta forma podrías utilizarlo simplemente así:

```
Producto unProducto = new Producto();

unProducto.Nombre = "Pelota";
ListaProductos.Add( new Producto(unProducto) );

unProducto.Nombre = "Auto";
ListaProductos.Add( new Producto(unProducto) );

unProducto.Nombre = "Avion";
ListaProductos.Add( new Producto(unProducto) );

// Ya asi.
```

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por responder estimado, una consulta, ¿como haría para declarar `unProducto`? ya que en el método constructor me estaría pidiendo un producto original. Gracias!

Comment: Lo edito para pasar un ejemplo mas completo.

Comment: Yo entendí tu ejemplo ese no es el problema, a lo que me refiero es que cuando pongo `Producto unProducto = new Producto();`, `Producto` espera un argumento y es un producto original que no existe porque lo estoy declarando por primera vez, no se si se entiende.

Comment: Ahora si. Puedes implementar la cantidad de constructores que desees, siempre que reciban diferentes parámetros (o ninguno). Por lo tanto, tendrías que declarar ademas, un constructor vacío para que sea tomado en dicho caso.

Answer (score 1):

Con objetos no se puede ya que con los objetos se guardan sus referencias, sin embargo, con una estructura sería posible ya que se pasan por valor.

```
public struct Persona
{
    public string Nombre;
}
```

Así ya podrás hacer lo que quieres

```
unProducto.Nombre = "Pelota";
ListaProductos.Add(unProducto);
unProducto.Nombre = "Auto";
ListaProductos.Add(unProducto);
```

Pero no podras modificar los elementos directamente de la lista:

```
 //Error
 ListaProductos[0].Nombre = "Balon";
```

Para modificar un elemento de la lista lo tendrías que sacar, modificarlo y guardarlo

```
unProducto = ListaProductos[0];
unProducto.Nombre = "Balon";
ListaProductos[0] = unProducto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Estuve trabajando en algo similar y esto me funcionó:
Primero en la entidad agregar un método clone

```
public Producto Clone(){
    return (Producto) this.MemberwiseClome();
}
```

Y en la capa datos una vez asignado el valor clonamos el elemento

```
lista.Add(producto.Clone())
```